# Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discussion, election

In about 5 hours, [the nomination phase of the moderator elections](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) is scheduled to end. However, in order for the election to proceed, it is necessary to have at least one more candidate running than there are slots. This allows for there to be actual voting phases, so that the community can actually show that they support the candidates who are running. Should there not be enough candidates come 20:00 UTC when the phase change would occur, the nomination phase will instead be extended for another 7 days.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless someone else wants to take on the responsibility. While the site is running quite well, we do need additional moderators. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: I really hope a few of the active people will step up and nominate themselves. As @GraceNote indicated, we really can use a new moderator now that Craig has resigned. If you have any questions about being a moderator, don't hesistate to contact me.

Comment: Looks like [Ron Maupin](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8499/ron-maupin) has stepped up to run. As that has happened before the end of the nomination phase, the election shall proceed as originally scheduled.

Comment: There's nothing like waiting until the last few minutes. :) I, too, was really hoping others would step up.

Comment: Thanks Ron for destroying NE. Nobody wants to participate in this community any more.

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf: ironic or real? Being a new user, I don't know Ron Maupin. Is there a meta post asking/discussing why Ron destroyed NE?

Comment: BTW: it seems that the election has ended. Why is this post still in the "hot meta posts" list? Can we remove it from there?

Comment: @Thomas Hot meta just reflects the most recent active and visited meta posts. Should fade away when more active stuff comes by, or in about 4 days if I recall correctly. It's mechanically grabbed so I can't directly remove it (as far as I'm aware)